# get item from treeView c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a TreeView

```
<TreeView Name="files" Margin="0,0,569,108" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding s1}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="CheckBox111" Checked="FileCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="FileCheckBox_Unchecked">
                        <ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                     <Image Source="file.jpg" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="20" Height="20" />
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                 </StackPanel>
                             </ContentPresenter.Content>
                         </ContentPresenter>
                     </CheckBox>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

and i want to check all the checkBoxs in the code-behind:

```
private void AllFilesCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Object item in (files as ItemsControl).Items)
    {
       TreeViewItem t = files.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as TreeViewItem;

       foreach (Object item1 in t.Items)
       {
          // TreeViewItem t2 = item1 as TreeViewItem;
         //  CheckBox t1 =item1 as CheckBox;
       }
   }
}
```

But I can not get access to the checkBox... I do not know how to get access to it.

thank you.

Edit: i tried the almulo's answer and i almost get it.
i have this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za2ho.png]

i want get to the content (marks in red in right), but i haven't child.Content

Comment: Do you have many check boxes?

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
            {
                if (depObj != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                    {
                        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                        if (child != null && child is T)
                        {
                            yield return (T)child;
                        }

                        foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                        {
                            yield return childOfChild;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void AllFilesCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var test = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(tvEmps);
            }
```

Comment: i edited my question, and i added picture, look there. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with your code you're only accessing the second level of all the items. Maybe in your case that's enough, but I'd make the method recursive so it works for any tree of any depth.

I use an extension method to look for the actual control, too, so it works even if the CheckBox is nested inside containers or placed among other controls.

```
private void AllFilesCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBoxes = GetAllCheckBoxes(files);

    foreach (var checkBox in checkBoxes)
    {
        // Do stuff with the CheckBoxes
    }
}

private List<CheckBox> GetAllCheckBoxes(ItemsControl itemsControl)
{
    var list = new List<CheckBox>();

    foreach (var item in itemsControl.Items)
    {
        var itemContainer = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        var checkBox = itemContainer.GetChildOfType<CheckBox>();

        if (checkBox != null)
            list.Add(checkBox);

        if (itemContainer is ItemsControl)
            list.AddRange(GetAllCheckBoxes(itemContainer));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Add the extension method to a different, static class:

```
public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) 
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null) return null;

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

        var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
        if (result != null) return result;
    }

    foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(depObj))
    {
        if (child is DependencyObject)
        {
            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: isn't working. i get just objects of SiteMember- the class that binding to the treeVIew. i want get the dataTemplate, no object of the class.

Comment: If you do `var itemContainer = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item)`, itemContainer should then be a TreeViewItem, and the CheckBox should be inside of it (so you should be able to find it with a method like `GetChildOfType`).  Keep in mind, though, that itemContainer could be `null` if its parent TreeViewItem is not expanded.

Comment: i edited my question, and i added picture, look there. thanks

Comment: I've added a search for logical children in my `GetChildOfType` extension method. This should help you find the CheckBoxes.

Comment: No, when the depObj is the right element, as the mode i gave in the picture, it arrives to the second loop, but his child is not DependencyObject... and it isn't no get in to the if.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var test = FindVisualChildren<TreeViewItem>(tvEmps);
        List<TreeViewItem> objtreeList = new List<TreeViewItem>();
        foreach (var item in test)
        {
            var chec = FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(item as TreeViewItem).Cast<CheckBox>();
            if ((chec.FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox).IsChecked == true)
            {
                var textblock = FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(item as TreeViewItem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not using `GetLogicalChildCollection` anywhere, I guess you'd want to use it along with `FindVisualChildren` to get all the childrens of the `TreeView`.