# TreeView created from sql database with Checkbox wpf

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, treeview

I create my `TreeView` with this piece of code (a method which returns `DataSet` and it will be equal to `TreeView's` `DataContext`):

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConString;
con.Open();

MySqlDataAdapter femda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM fem_table", con);
MySqlDataAdapter fileda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM file_table", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
femda.Fill(ds, "fem_table");
fileda.Fill(ds, "file_table");

DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("DataRelationship",
ds.Tables["fem_table"].Columns["fem_guid"],
ds.Tables["file_table"].Columns["fk_gfem_guid"],true);

dr.Nested = true;
ds.Relations.Add(dr);
return ds;
```

I use `HierarchialDataTemplate` to fill the `TreeView`. In `HierarchialDataTemplate`, I have `CheckBox`. I want to reach the data of selected rows. I made some research but they are done with a new class and data from database is added to List of this class. How can I reach the data of selected rows if I use this way to fill the `TreeView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111740/get-item-from-treeview-c-sharp

I used this post to solve the problem. I hope it helps!